# Create relation one-to-many without Foreign Key in nhibernate4

Tags: c#, nhibernate, db2, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-4

i'm new to NHibernate 4 and i try to create a one-to-many relation between two table in DB2, the tables don't have a foreign key and i can't edit the tables.
When debug the application i catch error in .saveorupdate method. 
The tables contains:

TLDMAIN->summary of article

TLDDETAIL->detail of article

Under the mapping of table,

TLDMAIN

```
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="NHibernateExample2"
                   namespace="NHibernateExample2.NHibernateMappings"
                   schema="RM2T4"
                   >
  <class name="TLDMAIN" table="TLDMAIN">
    <id name="DGINAD" column="DGINAD"    type="System.String">
      <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="DGSEDE" column="DGSEDE"    type="System.String" />
    <property name="DGZONA" column="DGZONA"    type="System.String" />
    <property name="DGCEOP" column="DGCEOP"    type="System.String" />
    <property name="DGSEDEC" column="DGSEDEC"   type="System.String" />
    <property name="DGZONAC" column="DGZONAC"   type="System.String" />
    <property name="DGCEOPC" column="DGCEOPC"   type="System.String" />
    <property name="DGRLAV" column="DGRLAV"    type="System.String" />
    <property name="DGCFDDL" column="DGCFDDL"   type="System.String" />
    <property name="DGCFLAV" column="DGCFLAV"   type="System.String" />
    <property name="DGDTDOM" column="DGDTDOM"   type="System.String" />
    <property name="DGTIPREGO" column="DGTIPREGO" type="System.String" />
    <property name="DGDTINTER" column="DGDTINTER" type="System.String" />
    <property name="DGNRATE" column="DGNRATE"   type="System.Int32" />
    <property name="DGIMPRATA" column="DGIMPRATA" type="System.Decimal" />
    <property name="DGPRECALC" column="DGPRECALC" type="System.String" />
    <property name="DGSTCORR" column="DGSTCORR"  type="System.String" />
    <property name="DGTIMEST" column="DGTIMEST"  type="System.String" />
    <property name="DGNOTE" column="DGNOTE"    type="System.String" />
    <bag name="periodi" table="TLDDETAIL" lazy="false">
      <key column="DDINAD" />
      <one-to-many class="NHibernateExample2.NHibernateMappings.TLDDETAIL" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

TLDDETAIL

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="NHibernateExample2"
                   namespace="NHibernateExample2.NHibernateMappings"
                   schema="RM2T4"
                   >
  <class name="TLDDETAIL" table="TLDDETAIL">
    <id name="DDINAD"     column="DDINAD"   type="System.String">
      <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="DDANNO"     column="DDANNO"   type="System.Int32" />
    <property name="DDTRIM"     column="DDTRIM"   type="System.Int32" />
    <property name="DDPROG"     column="DDPROG"   type="System.Int32" />
    <property name="DDORERET"   column="DDORERET" type="System.Int32" />
    <property name="DDTIPCAL"   column="DDTIPCAL" type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDRETEFF"   column="DDRETEFF" type="System.Decimal" />
    <property name="DDSETALL"   column="DDSETALL" type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDSETT1"    column="DDSETT1"  type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDSETT2"    column="DDSETT2"  type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDSETT3"    column="DDSETT3"  type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDSETT4"    column="DDSETT4"  type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDSETT5"    column="DDSETT5"  type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDSETT6"    column="DDSETT6"  type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDSETT7"    column="DDSETT7"  type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDSETT8"    column="DDSETT8"  type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDSETT9"    column="DDSETT9"  type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDSETT10"   column="DDSETT10" type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDSETT11"   column="DDSETT11" type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDSETT12"   column="DDSETT12" type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDSETT13"   column="DDSETT13" type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDSETT14"   column="DDSETT14" type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDSETT15"   column="DDSETT15" type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDINTEGR"   column="DDINTEGR" type="System.String" />
    <property name="DATEPAG"    column="DATEPAG"  type="System.String" />
    <property name="FLAGPAG"    column="FLAGPAG"  type="System.String" />
    <property name="DDPARTITA"  column="DDPARTITA" type="System.String"/>
    <property name="DDPROGPART" column="DDPROGPART" type="System.String"/>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The error it's 
No persister for: NHibernateExample2.NHibernateMappings.TLDMAIN

In google i found the cause of this error, it's error in mapping but i don't have found this.

Thank's for help!!!

Comment: *the tables don't have a foreign key* Then how should the TLDDetail be "joined" to the TLDMAIN rows? There must be some information somewhere

Comment: when they created the table they used the logical keys, the two PK tables are identical, it is unfortunately an old DB created in the wrong way.

Comment: That error isn't normally caused by problems with the keys, but by problems with the mappings. Check that the mappings (xml files) are set as Embedded Resource (Properties on the xml file, Build Action, Embedded Resource)

Comment: Then look in the config file where there is the <session-factory> section, and check that there is a row like `<mapping assembly="NHibernateExample2"/>`

Comment: the problem was on the configuration of the property as embedded. Thaks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error doesn't seems to be connected to problems with the foreign keys. It seems to be that the NHibernate can't find the XML files. The "common" problems are normally three:

- The XML files must be set (in their Properties) with the Build Action = Embedded Resource
- In the configuration file where there is the `<session-factory>` section (normally app.config/web.config), there should be a `<mapping assembly="NHibernateExample2"/>` (or whatever the assembly with the mappings is named)
- Third possibility, where you load the NHibernate configuration, perhaps you forgot the to do the `configuration.Configure()` (because doing `NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration configuration = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();` isn't enough, you have to do `configuration.Configure()`)